# Swift installTap using bluetooth mic produces "chipmunk" audio

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, audio-recording

When using a bluetooth mic and recording the output from installTap, I am getting a high-pitched, very fast playback.

### Using bluetooth:

installTap -> High-pitched, fast playback

AVAudioRecorder -> Normal, as intended

### Using Apple's earphone mic:

installTap -> Normal, as intended

AVAudioRecorder -> Normal, as intended

Any idea why this is happening? If AVAudioRecorder is able to record the bluetooth input as intended, why am I getting a high-pitched, fast playback when recording through installTap?

installTap:

```
let format = mixer.outputFormat(forBus: 0)

let _bufferSize : AVAudioFrameCount = 4096

mixer.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: _bufferSize, format: format) { 
(buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in
        try self.outputFile.write(from: buffer)
}
```

Output file:

```
try self.outputFile = AVAudioFile(forWriting: outputFile, settings: self._settings)
```

_settings:

```
let _settings = [
    AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: 1,
    AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: 1,
    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
    AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 32,
    AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: 0,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.low.rawValue
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem solved.

Turns out, the bluetooth mic's sample rate is set to 8000 kHz, hence the fast, high-pitched sound. The problem here is, we cannot set the input's settings.

To remedy this, I had to insert a new node between the input node and the output node, set that new node's sampling rate to 44,100 kHz, then tap on that new node instead of the main node.

```
// our new node
var k44mixer = AVAudioMixerNode()

// the input node, which is currently the bluetooth mic
let input = engine.inputNode!
let inputFormat = input.inputFormat(forBus: 0)

// format for the new node
let k44format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 2, interleaved: false)

// attach the new node to the audio engine
engine.attach(self.k44mixer)

// connect input to the new node, using the input's format
engine.connect(input, to: self.k44mixer, format: inputFormat)
// connect the new node to the output node
engine.connect(self.k44mixer, to: engine.outputNode, format: k44format)

// tap on the new node
self.k44mixer.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: self.k44mixer.outputFormat(forBus: 0), block:
        { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in

            print(NSString(string: "writing"))
            do {
                try self.outputFile.write(from: buffer)
            }
            catch {
                print(NSString(string: "Write failed"));
            }
    })
```

Hope this helps anyone out there. This had me scratching my head for more than a week! Cheers!

Comment: Also, I'm suspecting that AVAudioRecorder is doing something similar when recording (inserting a node with different settings), that's why it comes out fine.

Comment: Hey, can you please see this code? https://github.com/jscalo/tempi-fft/blob/master/TempiFFT/TempiAudioInput.swift It receives audio from microphone without installing a Tap on it. Unfortunately when I change the 'setPreferredIOBufferDuration' paremeter it doesn't change the bufferSize.. =/ Do you think this is wrongly implemented?